# Sending email to email address retrieved from database Initiated by session in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm attempting to create a system when you initiate a session an email
 is then sent to the email the user created the account with. I'm
 having an error which i've tried to solve, but I'm unable to.  Here is

> the error:
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\LoginSystem\index.php on line 37
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_assoc() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\LoginSystem\index.php on line 42

I'm very new to php and have been using snippets but obviously not
 applying them correctly.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

require 'assests/database.php';

session_start();


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to your web app</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" stype="text/css" href="assests/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
</head>



<body>


<div class="header">
  <a href="index.php"> Your App Name</a>
</div>  


<?php if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ): ?>



<?php



    $sql = 'select email from noodles_gamification where ID = "'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'"';

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $email = "";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $email = $row["email"];
    }


    /*
    $recipients = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($stmt)) {
        $recipients = $row[0]['email'];
    } */

    $to = $email;
    $subject = "E-mail subject";
    $body = "E-mail body";
    $headers = "From: noreply@prakashsoft.esy.es" ;

    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);








?>



<br /> Welcome you are succesfully loggin in!

<a href="assests/logout.php">Logout?</a>
<?php else : ?>



<h1>Please login or register</h1>
<a href="assests/login.php">login</a> or 
<a href="assests/register.php">Register</a>


<?php endif; ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `NOTICE` message says, that you try to convert an `array` to `string`. It seems that your session includes an array.

The error message says, that `PDOStatement::fetch_assoc()` does not exist.
The method you were looking for is `PDOStatement::fetch()`, see http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php

As you only want to get one email address (I suppose the ID in your table is unique), you would not need any loop. 
You may therefore replace your `while` loop through:

```
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$email = $row["email"];
```